# Treeview Node ToolTip is displaying the wrong information

Tags: c#, treeview, tooltip

I am using C#, Windows Forms, TreeView Control. 
I assign ToolTipText at node creation.
On nodes that I have assigned a ToolTipText value, the correct text is properly displayed. 
On all other nodes, the Node Name is displayed when there should not be any ToolTip displayed at all.
I've tried to assign null string at node creation for those nodes not having tooltip text ... but it doesn't work.

Comment: show us the code you have so far, the input that goes in and the output that comes out.  Then, show us the output you desire...

Comment: I appreciate your redirection but I don't think code is the problem here. I am probably missing a key detail. I will try to rephrase the problem, hopefully clearer than before.The hover over ToolTip works great for nodes where a value is assigned to the ToolTipText property. On all other nodes I do not want any hover over tooltip to display at all! What I do get however is the name of the node displaying as a hover over tooltip, when I want nothing at all.

Comment: Since you keep your code to yourself, I can't but assure you, that nodes without a tooltiptext don't show anything here. So I guess your code contains some problems..

Comment: There is no scenario where the TreeNode.Name property is ever displayed in a tooltip.  Its Text property can appear if the node doesn't fit the width of the TreeView.  Repro code is required to get help.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The Node.Text property was being displayed on all nodes because the node text was longer than the size of the treeView control. All the treenode levels have different background color and I  padded the text to fill the space, for formatting purposes.  Thank you for making  the effort, this solved my problem. I looked for a reference to this after I saw your solution but I did not see this documented anywhere. Is it appropriate for you to post this as a "Solution".  Thank you again.